# add multiple picturebox to a main Picturebox and draw them

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a main `PictureBox` which adding to it , an other picture boxes; I pass the parent to the children and add them to the parent as follow :

```
public class VectorLayer : PictureBox
    {
        Point start, end;
        Pen pen;

        public VectorLayer(Control parent)
        {
            pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255), 8);
            pen.StartCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
            pen.EndCap = LineCap.RoundAnchor;
            parent.Controls.Add(this);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Location = new Point(0, 0);

        }


        public void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, end, start);
        }

        public void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            start = e.Location;
        }

        public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            end = e.Location;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            end = e.Location;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

and am handling those `On Events` from inside the main `PictureBox`, now in the main `PictureBox` am handling on the `Paint` event as follow:

```
 private void PicBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
//current layer is now an instance of `VectorLayer` which is a child of this main picturebox
        if (currentLayer != null)
        {
            currentLayer.OnPaint(this, e);
        }
        e.Graphics.Flush();
        e.Graphics.Save();
    }
```

but when I draw nothing appears , when I do `Alt+Tab` lose the focus from it , I see my vector , when I try to draw again and lose focus nothing happens..

why is that weird behavior and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where is `currentLayer` set?

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht inside `OnMouseClick` event , and I call `Invalidate()` `OnMouseMove` event.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to **hook up** your events.

Add these lines to your class:

```
MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
MouseUp += OnMouseUp;
Paint += OnPaint;
```

Not sure if you don't maybe want this in the `MouseMove`:

```
public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) 
    {
        end = e.Location;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Aslo these lines are useless and should be removed:

```
    e.Graphics.Flush();
    e.Graphics.Save();
```

`GraphicsState oldState = Graphics.Save` would save the current state, ie the setting of the current Graphics object. Useful if you need to toggle between several states, maybe scales or clipping or rotation or translation etc.. But not here!

`Graphics.Flush`  flushes all pending graphics operations, but there is really no reason to suspect that there are any in your application.